# How to hide column by grid details?

Tags: c#, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid and a detail grid which looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SDB.Models.NettoVergelijking.Dienstverband>()
        .Name("overzicht-grid")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(d => d.Naam).Title("Medewerker").ClientTemplate("<span title='${Naam}'>${Naam}</span>").Width(300)
                .Filterable(f =>
                {
                    f.Extra(false);
                    f.Operators(op =>
                    {
                        op.ForString(str =>
                        {
                            str.Clear().Contains("Bevat");
                        });
                    });
                });
            columns.Bound(d => d.Contractvorm).Title("Contractvorm").ClientTemplate("<span title='${Contractvorm}'>${Contractvorm}</span>").Width(200).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true)); 
            columns.Bound(d => d.Run1.Netto).Title("periode1").Filterable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Width(220).ClientTemplate("# if (Run1.Netto != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(Run1.Netto, 'n2') #  # } #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
            columns.Bound(d => d.Run2.Netto).Title("Periode 2").Filterable(true).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Width(220).ClientTemplate("# if (Run2.Netto != 0) { #  #= kendo.toString(Run2.Netto, 'n2') #  # } #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
           columns.Bound(d => d.VerschilPercentage).Filterable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;", @class = "NettoVergelijkingVerschil" }).ClientTemplate("# if (VerschilPercentage != 0) { # %   #= kendo.toString(VerschilPercentage, 'n2') #  # } else { # % 0  # } #").Width(165).Format("{0:P}").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Hidden();
           columns.Bound(d => d.Verschil).Filterable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;", @class = "NettoVergelijkingVerschil" }).ClientTemplate("# if (Verschil != 0) { #  € #= kendo.toString(Verschil, 'n2') #    # } else { # €  0,00  # } #").Width(165).Format("{0: #.00}").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
        })
    .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new List<object>
        { 25, 50, 100, 200, 500 }))
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("overzicht-grid-details")
        .Excel(e => e.AllPages(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(d => d.Id);
            model.Field(f => f.Naam);
            model.Field(f => f.Contractvorm);
            model.Field(f => f.Run1.Netto);
            model.Field(f => f.Run2.Netto);
        })
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetOverzicht", "NettoVergelijking").Data("getData"))
        .Sort(d => d.Add(a => a.Verschil).Descending()
        )
        )
)

<script id="overzicht-grid-details" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SDB.Models.NettoVergelijking.Detail>()
                .Name("overzicht-grid1-details-#=Id#")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Omschrijving).Width(270)
                        .Filterable(false).HeaderTemplate(" ");
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Belastbaarheid).Width(200).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "cursor:pointer;" });
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Waarde1).Width(220)
                        .ClientTemplate("\\# if (Waarde1 != 0 && Waarde1 != null) { \\#  \\#= kendo.toString(Waarde1, 'n2') \\#  \\# } else { \\#  \\# } \\#")
                        .ClientFooterTemplate("\\#=kendo.toString(sum, 'n2')\\#")
                        .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Filterable(false).HeaderTemplate(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Waarde2).Width(220)
                        .ClientTemplate("\\# if (Waarde2 != 0 && Waarde2 != null) { \\#  \\#= kendo.toString(Waarde2, 'n2') \\#  \\# } else { \\#  \\# } \\#")
                        .ClientFooterTemplate("\\#=kendo.toString(sum, 'n2')\\#")
                        .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Filterable(false).HeaderTemplate(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Verschil)
                        .ClientTemplate("\\# if (Verschil != 0 && Verschil != null) { \\# € \\#= kendo.toString(Verschil, 'n2') \\#  \\# } else {  \\# €   0  \\# } \\#")
                        .ClientFooterTemplate("\\#=kendo.toString(sum, 'n2')\\#")
                        .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Filterable(false).HeaderTemplate(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" });
                    columns.Bound(o => o.VerschilPercentage)
                       .ClientTemplate("\\# if (VerschilPercentage != 0 && Verschil != null) { \\# % \\#= kendo.toString(VerschilPercentage, 'n2') \\# % \\# } else { \\# 0  \\# } \\#")
                       .ClientFooterTemplate("\\#=kendo.toString(sum, 'n2')\\#")
                       .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Filterable(false).HeaderTemplate(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right;" }).Hidden();
                })
                .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Aggregates(a =>
                    {
                        a.Add(x => x.Waarde1).Sum();
                        a.Add(x => x.Waarde2).Sum();
                        a.Add(x => x.Verschil).Sum();
                        a.Add(x => x.VerschilPercentage).Sum();
                    })
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(d => d.Id);
                        model.Field(f => f.Type);
                        model.Field(f => f.Omschrijving);
                        model.Field(f => f.Waarde1);
                        model.Field(f => f.Waarde2);
                        model.Field(f => f.Verschil);
                        model.Field(f => f.VerschilPercentage);
                    })
                    .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.Type))
                    .Sort(s => s.Add(a => a.LoonfactorCode).Ascending())
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetPeriodeDetails", "NettoVergelijking", new { dienstverbandId = "#=Id#" }).Data("getData"))
                )
                .ToClientTemplate()
    )
```

and I have javascript for hiding/ showing the specific column, like this:

```
        $("#euro-switch").kendoMobileSwitch({
            onLabel: "%",
            offLabel: "€",
            change: function (e) {

                var label = e.sender.value() ? e.sender.options.onLabel : e.sender.options.offLabel.toString();
                var grid = $("#overzicht-grid").data("kendoGrid");
                var gridDetail = $("#overzicht-grid-details").data("kendoGrid");
                if (e.checked) {
                    grid.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                    grid.hideColumn('Verschil')                            

                    //detail
                    gridDetail.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                    gridDetail.hideColumn("Verschil");
                }
                else {
                    grid.hideColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                    grid.showColumn("Verschil");                           

                    //Detail:
                     gridDetail.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
                     gridDetail.hideColumn("Verschil");

                }

                var inpbox = $('#SignalThreshold').data("kendoNumericTextBox");
                inpbox.setOptions(
                    {
                        format: "\\" + label + "\\ #",
                        decimals: 2
                    });
                inpbox.value(inpbox.value());
            }

        });
```

But I get the message: Index:611 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showColumn' of undefined on the detail grid.

And if I look in chrome and press F12, then I see for the detail grid the id:

overzicht-grid1-details-329684. So it is with a number, but the number changed every time.

So my question is: how to solve this problem that it will not add a number to the detail grid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be related to your change event handler, where `gridDetail` is undefined.

You are defining your variable with `var gridDetail = $("#overzicht-grid-details").data("kendoGrid");` but as you said, the id is defined with an Id variable in the template: `.Name("overzicht-grid1-details-#=Id#")`.

So you could query for partial ids and iterate over the result set:

```
var detailGrids = $("[id*=overzicht-grid-details]");
detailGrids.forEach((index, detailGrid) => {
    gridDetail = gridDetail.data("kendoGrid");
    gridDetail.showColumn("VerschilPercentage");
    gridDetail.hideColumn("Verschil");
});
```

You will run into another problem after solving the first one:
No detail grid is initialized unless you expand it. So if you toggle a switch, without a child grid being initialized it won't hide or show the columns as you like.

A simple, yet unelegant, solution would be to let the switch set a global-ish variable and check that variable, in your dataBound and change event of all grids:

```
change: function(e) { //do the same for dataBound in the grids and/or refactor in seperate function
    if(someVariable === true) { //some variable is set by the switch
        //show or hide columns
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I have to do then? I don't get it

Comment: Try it out. When you stumble upon it, you will know what I mean.